# Does the phase space exist in reality?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, definition, phase-space

The concept of phase space really bothers me sometimes and the term is used across many branches of physics such as statistical mechanics, classical mechanics as well as in quantum mechanics. Does [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) really exist in the real-world like real space (3D), the volume of which is determined mathematically by taking the length element along with three different directions (such as $x,y,z$) or it is purely a mathematical concept that means a set of position and momentum coordinates? If exist, is it proven experimentally?

Comment: this article clears the question imo, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "exists". It just sounds like phase space is a just all the possibilities. It sounds like you're completely misunderstanding by applying the layman usage of "space" to math, where mathematicians are mean something quite different when they say "space". For example, if I say the space of real numbers. It just means all possible real numbers. This might be a language thing if English is not your native language.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what "exists in reality" is a question about [philosophy.se], not physics.

Comment: A coordinate system is also a mathematical object. The description is not the thing described.

Comment: Good mathematical descriptions exist in reality, in physics.  Real 3D space is one of them, and so is phase space. Physics describes reality.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it "exists", though there's maybe some wiggle-room about the definition of that word, as much as anything else exists. Just because you don't directly experience phase space in the same way that you directly experience $(x,y,z,t)$ isn't a reason to suggest it doesn't exist. You do experience it indirectly through the observable behavior of systems. Likewise, for example, you directly experience visible light photons, but don't directly experience radio wave photons. Nevertheless, you wouldn't claim that non-visible electromagnetic radiation doesn't exist. So you likewise shouldn't be suggesting that phase space doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Phase space representation of a dynamical system that exists in 3-D space plus time is a mathematical abstraction that's a useful problem-solving tool in physics and engineering mechanics. As such, it is just as "real" as anything else can be said to be in mathematics even though there is no location in our universe where phase space can be said to physically exist in the same sense as the dynamical systems it describes.

So phase space contains a mathematical representation of a physical system but it does not contain the physical system itself.

Answer (score -2):

Good question! I asked myself too. And my conclusion is that it's just our fabrication. Particles move in space only. The different positions, the varying of their mutual distances with time, are used to define  momenta, defining the half of phasespace. A particle moves in space only. Not in a 6D phasespace. We have to make two measurements of position and time to construct the momentum part.

The picture that a particle or system moves in phasespace, like on a circle for an harmonically oscillating particle, is misleading but useful. The particle moves in space half only. Not in the momentum half, as it has no velocity in the phase half. You can read the force acting on the particle (dp/dt), which for the oscillating particle is maximum for x=u (when p=0), the amplitude of the oscillation, and 0 for x=0 (when p is max). You can even extend the phasespace to 9 dimensions, including force. Particles have velocity, and forces on them are real, but a motion through the phasespace is not happening.

Measuring momentum is problematic, as it involves two measurements of position. And how do we measure two arbitrarily close positions? Does instantaneous velocity exist? A problem that surfaces even more in QM. But that aside.

Comment: You say "A particle only moves through space ... [a particle] has no velocity in the [velocity half of phase space]". This is objectively untrue when the particle is accelerating, since the rate of change of the velocity - 'the velocity of the velocity' - is non-zero. When the particle has constant velocity, only then does the particle stay still in velocity space.